# iOS:How to add shadow to`tabbar`?

Tags: ios, shadow, tabbar

I have a test to add shadow to my `tabbar`, but it show no use.My code is below:

```
    _button.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    _button.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(4,4);
    _button.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
    _button.layer.shadowRadius = 4;

    /* remove tab-line */
    [[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] init]];
    [self.tabBarController.tabBar setClipsToBounds:YES];

    self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor;
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,-4);
    self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8;
   self.tabBarController.tabBar.layer.shadowRadius = 4;
```

And I also taken a photo to show that:

[image: the button has shadow but tabbar has nothing]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create image with shadow, Then use as follow.

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage alloc] INITWITHYOURCUSTOMIMAGE]]; 
[[UITabBar appearance] setShadowImage:[[UIImage alloc] INITWITHYOURCUSTOMIMAGE]];
```

In swift:

```
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage(named:"YOURIMAGE")
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage(named:"YOURIMAGE")
```